# 4GB RAM I915GM SERIES SOCKET 775 MOTHERBOARD

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios

Hello this question may be so silly or asked many times but I posting it to find the correct answer

My Motherboard is I915GM SERIES MANUFACTURED BY LORD ELECTRONICS CO.,LTD

I just got 2x2GB sticks until then I have 2x1gb sticks on the board

When I install new sticks there is a "no display" error i.e "post error" with system but with only stick it works fine

I also tried 1x1Gb and 1x2Gb combination it only recognises 2Gb

i would like to know is there a way to use both 2Gb rams .

I had also searched to check if motherboard supports these ram but I cannot find a page regarding that.

Comment: When installing memory, make sure the manufacturer, capacity, and speed of the memory is supported by your motherboard. Make sure you do not exceed the maximum memory total as well as max memory per dimm slot.

Comment: That's the Problem is I doesnt know what is max for the board

Comment: Seems that a simple google search shows that 2GB is the max.

Comment: @EricF I have also seen 4GB that's where I got confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's not possible. The I915GM does not support more than 2GB of RAM. You can check the [specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/27715/Intel-82915GM-Graphics-and-Memory-Controller):

> Max Memory Size: 2 GB

Comment: Thanks for Answer Please can I know does using dual slot is better or single slot let me know

Comment: @DevelopersWork - It provides a slight performance increase. It also does not matter, your motherboard does not support more then 2 GB of memory, so the only way to use dual-channel is to use your 1 GB memory modules.  You are unlikely to actually see any performance increases outside of a situation where you are doing benchmarks.

Comment: Yep. Using two slots (one on each channel) does provide a significant boost to memory performance as measured on synthetic benchmarks. But with realistic workloads, only a very slight boost to overall performance. (Usually, you get the best performance by using two memory sticks of the same size and placing them with an empty slot between them.)